# how to draw alphabets using particles in html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

while browsing on internet I came across Yalantis and got amazed by its particle slider of "Y". Now, I want to create my name initial like they have created. using particles.(not particlejs i am quite sure about it).

Please anyone can help me out how can I draw my initials just the mentioned example here is the link btw to have a look
https://yalantis.com/

I have tried to generate random particles but I want to generate my initials
thanks :)

Comment: Create an offscreen canvas. Render the text you want on it. Get the pixel data with `context.getImageData` Use that pixel data to determine where particles need to go to make the text and then render the  particle FX. Each of these steps can be found on Stackoverflow (SO).

Comment: any good tutorial or reference in your view? it would be great if I get one I'm kinda newbie in canvas. :)